# How can iOS7 untethered energy/network recordings be accessed?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, xcode-instruments

iOS7 has a preference under " Preferences | Developer | Instruments / Logging | Untethered Recording" to record the energy and network usage data.

How do I extract this from the device to view in Xcode or Instruments?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This basically records the same data that would get recorded if you were running the *Energy Diagnostics* or *Network* instruments while the device is plugged in, except it'll keep logging in the background all the time without the need for a tethered Instruments session.

You'll need to be running the version of Instruments provided in Xcode 5 (or newer) for this to work.  Make sure you have you device plugged in before starting Instruments.

First step is to create a new Trace Document using the corresponding Instrument Template in Instruments' New screen:

[image: Instruments New Screen]

Now, in the File menu, a new option *Import Logged Data from Device* should be available, if you have your device plugged in.

[image: Import Logged Data from Device]

You should now see the results from your last run.  You *don't* have to stop logging on your device to access this option, it'll just give you the data between when you started recording to when you pressed the import button.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to filter logged data to a specific process?

Comment: I am trying to do this, but the "Import Logged Data from Device" is greyed out. Any ideas on why? The device has the proper profiles.

Comment: I am testing this using Instruments 7.3.1 (7D1014) and an iPhone 5S (iOS 9.3.5) and it is not working... :-( Could someone try this and tell me if it is a problem with my setup or with the software ? Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

This Apple page explains the whole process: [Energy Efficiency Guide for iOS Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/MonitorEnergyWithInstruments.html)

To import logged energy data from an iOS device

1. Launch Instruments and create a new trace document that targets your device and app with the Energy Diagnostics profiling template.
   [image: Choose Instruments template]
2. Choose File > Import Logged Data from Device.

[image: Import Logged Data from Device]

Comment: is it possible to import multiple runs from one device or do I need to stop and plug it in and import after each run?